# Doing math operations on Scala objects in Java code

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

In my java code I am using a method, let's call `foo()`, that returns a `scala.Double[]`.

```java
scala.Double[] arr = foo();
```

I want to sum up `arr` into a `scala.Double`, but am having trouble. I've found that doing any kind of math operation on `scala.Double`s gets me an error message from my IDE:

```java
arr[0] + arr[1];
arr[0] * arr[1];
//etc
```

get me messages like

`Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'scala.Double', 'scala.Double'`

How can I do math operations on `scala.Double`s within java code? (alternatively, is there another way to sum up a `scala.Double[]` within java code?)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you got `scala.Double[]` in Java. If you have `Array[Double]` in Scala, it's seen in Java as `double[]`, not `scala.Double[]`.

Anyway, if you have `scala.Double[]` in Java

```
public class App {
  public static scala.Double[] arr = foo();
}
```

then it's seen in Scala also as `Array[scala.Double]`

```
object App1 {
  val arr1: Array[Double] = App.arr
}
```

and then the latter is seen back in Java as `double[]`

```
public class App {
  public static scala.Double[] arr = foo();
  public static double[] arr2 = App1.arr1();
}
```

Then you can do `arr2[0] + arr2[1]`, `arr2[0] * arr2[1]`...